# JSP Expression resolving

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I'm new to JSP and I found this in the tag file:

```
<c:when test="${fooRequest.fooEnabled}">
```

`fooRequest` is an instance of `FooRequest`. But in the class file, there is no definition of `fooEnabled`! There is a function called `isFooEnabled`. Will it call `isFooEnabled` automatically when the statement is tested?

For some reason, I cannot debug it. But I'm sure the tag file runs fine.

Comment: Better if you use `JSTL` tag library instead of JSP

Comment: Just hover over the `jsp` tag in your question and it the info link: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info

Comment: `<%--` denotes the start of a JSP comment. This expression will not be evaluated.

Comment: @McDowell Sorry It's a typo.

Comment: You don't you try it by making a simple program that will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression Language (EL) in JSP follows bean convention : `${foo.bar}` does the following :

- locates a scoped variable (in page, request or session context) named `foo`
- if `foo` has a method `getBar()` take its value
- else if `foo` has a method `isBar()` returning a `boolean` (or `Boolean`) takes its value

you can also have subscripts for `List` or `Map` such as `${foo.bar[2]}` or `${foo.bar['x']}`

You will find further details on [- The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) or [The Java EE 7 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc//home.htm), chapter *Expression Language*